# Mocking a function that is called during file load in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a file which I am trying to unit test. I wish to test that the API object is created by calling the `feathers` and `auth` library methods as well as testing that the exported `login` and `logout` methods call the appropriate library methods.

I would like to mock all calls to the library methods so as to just unit test this file.

This is what I have so far:

**api.js**

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import auth from '@feathersjs/authentication-client'

export const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30

const api = feathers()
api.configure(auth({ storage: window.localStorage, timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * 1000 }))

const login = async (credentials) => {
  return api.authenticate(credentials)
}

const logout = async () => {
  return api.logout()
}

export default { login, logout }
```

**api.test.js**

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import auth from '@feathersjs/authentication-client'

import api, { DEFAULT_TIMEOUT } from './api'

const mockFeathers = {
  configure: jest.fn(),
  authenticate: jest.fn(),
  logout: jest.fn()
}
jest.mock('@feathersjs/feathers', () => jest.fn(() => mockFeathers))
jest.mock('@feathersjs/authentication-client', () => jest.fn(() => 'AUTH'))

describe('helpers/api', () => {
  it('creates a Feathers app with authentication', () => {
    expect(feathers).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(auth).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      storage: window.localStorage,
      timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * 1000
    })

    expect(mockFeathers.configure).toHaveBeenCalledWith('AUTH')
  })

  describe('login', () => {
    it('authenticates with the Feathers app', async () => {
      const loginResult = { loggedIn: true }
      mockFeathers.authenticate.mockImplementationOnce(() => loginResult)

      const credentials = { email: 'user@example.com', password: 'password' }
      const result = await api.login(credentials)

      expect(mockFeathers.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(credentials)
      expect(result).toEqual(loginResult)
    })
  })

  describe('logout', () => {
    it('logs out from the Feathers app', async () => {
      await api.logout()

      expect(mockFeathers.logout).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

This fails with `ReferenceError: mockFeathers is not defined` because it seems that `api.js` is being loaded (and therefore the `feathers` method called) before `mockFeathers` is defined. I have tried moving the `import api` line below the definition of `mockFeathers` but that doesn't make a difference.

How can I mock the result of the `feathers()` call before the `api.js` file is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to achieve this by removing the import entirely and `require`ing the `api.js` in a `beforeAll` block. This works but seems a little messy to me, and wouldn't scale well if you had multiple individual imports from the `require`d file.

**api.test.js**

```
// Remove the import line.
//import api, { DEFAULT_TIMEOUT } from './api'

describe('helpers/api', () => {
  let api, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
  beforeAll(() => {
    // Require the file here so that the mock has time to be defined.
    ;({ default: api, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT } = require('./api'))
  })

  // ...
})
```